# Create a relation between a MongoDB and a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, sql-update, relation

I have a server with 2 databases: a NoSQL (MongoDB) and a SQL (MySQL).
In MySQL database I manage the users and other stuff.
In MongoDB I manage different things like posts.

The problem comes with this:
I want to implement a "change username" method, which changes the username of the user in the MySQL database and in some sort of way changes the username related to a post. The username of that user can be found in every collection in the MongoDB database.

Is there any way to perform what I need?

Comment: Do you want to implement a "change username" stored procedure in MySQL or a method within your application?

Comment: I don't really care, the more I can do directly on the database the better it is because if there are other options I wouldn't like to check in every single collection to rename if present

Comment: If the user is able to update his user name frequently then you should reconsider the place of the user name value within MongoDB and go with a identifier stored within for example user collection. Then you would only have to update the user collection instead of all the other collections. What do you think?